# How to maintain same Code for different clients with few CSS or Component changes?

Tags: java, angular, optimization

I have same Angular 6 code for 2 or more clients but while I move the build, I have to manually comment few things for particular client. For example, lets say I have client X and Y, for client X i have different Style.Scss and for client Y its different. We maintain code using tortoiseSVN, How can I make sure that the change in files happens automatically while building the code? 
Front end is Angular 6 , Back end is Java .

Comment: i am new to this but Can I understand why there is a down vote without an answer  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply css class based on flag.

```
let flag = 'x'; // E.x now x client is active.
```

In html

```
// For css stuff
<div [ngClass]="x ? 'xClass' ? 'yClass'">
</div>

// For show content 
<div *ngIf="flag == 'x'">
    // Show data of x user 
</div>

<div *ngIf="flag == 'y'">
    // Show data of y user 
</div>
```

With that you have to manage with backend also by sending flag also.

**Update**

When it's matter of whole component I suggest you to use diffrent auth guard. It is the best thing for this type of situation.

Comment: I understand css can be changed in this way, I can use "SetAttribute" to just call CSS and I already have done it, but this is a after build scenario, while I want some script to take care of it while I build.

Comment: It's not mean that if your code will work on dev then it will not work in build. It will also work on build. Even I'm using ihis way. And it works for me.

Comment: Just you have to take care of flag in both side.

Answer (score 1):

You should use different class for different clients on body element so that you can style children's according to the client X or client Y.

For instance while initialising the application add class 'clientx' to body and then write css rules with respect to clientx as parent.

When you're building application for clientX, add class clientx to body and respective child elements can be styled

```
body.clientx .elementA{
     color:red
}
```

Similarly, When you're building application for clientY, add class clienty to body and respective child elements can be styled

```
body.clienty .elementA{
     color:yellow
}
```

This way you don't have to touch the angular logic and css itself can handle your requirement. For more robust implementation you may use scss.